# Is it possible to remove constant "beep" sound from recording?

Tags: audio, microphone, recording

Whenever I record with my microphone, I get this constant beep sound on the background. It appears only when I turn volume up, so it is not very loud, but its noticable and pretty annoying.

Because it is constant sound, I thought it should be possible to filter just that one frequency, but I have absolutely no idea how to do it.

Comment: Are you using a free trial version of a commercial product to do your recording?

Comment: Are you recording this onto a computer? If so, then it's probably some noise generated by the internals of the machine. I've heard this before and I suspect this happens when you have a crappy integrated soundcard.

Comment: If it's a constant tone, it could be signal noise generated by the recording equipment. A cheap mic, cheap cables, and cheap audio interfaces will have these noise problems. What are you using to record with? Any specific details to your setup (devices and ports used) would really help tell you what is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to use something like Adobe Audition to do frequency space editing and remove the beep.  This lets you edit at the frequency level so you could mute just the part of the spectrum that the beep is on.

Are you using the built-in microphone jack?  If so, I suspect that the beep is coming from your hard drive and a poorly designed motherboard layout.  You might get a USB audio device, even one of the small "gumstick" devices.  This will isolate your audio from the electronics inside the computer and should cause it to go away.

Comment: Even though Adobe Audition crashed every time I start it, I downloaded Adobe Soundbooth and it's "Remove noise" function works wonders

Comment: Glad to hear it Darth!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question right, the free [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) sound editor should be able to do what you want.  I also agree with Steve Rowe's suggestion that a better mike is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My beeping was from the metronome being on. Its at the bottom of the screen to the right of the tempo. Click it to off. Hope this helps